# Maxima texput for sqrt function

Tags: tex, maxima, wxmaxima

I was trying to redefine the output for `sqrt()` in Maxima, using texput, but am getting an error that I can't make sense of.

This is the function I wrote for creating the desired string:

```
sqrt_tex:lambda([e], printf(false,"\\csqrt{~a}", tex1(e)))
```

When applied to an expression, it seems to behave as expected:

```
sqrt_tex(2);
   > \csqrt{2}
```

but after passing `texput('sqrt, sqrt_tex, prefix);` when I try:

```
tex1(sqrt(2))
    > Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
 ((LAMBDA SIMP) ((MLIST) $E) (($PRINTF) NIL "\\csqrt{~a}" $E)) is not a string designator.
Automatically continuing.
To enable the Lisp debugger set *debugger-hook* to nil.
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On a whim, I removed `prefix` and that seems to work. I assumed `sqrt` was a prefix operator because `sin` and `cos` are (I believe) and I thought they'd be defined similarly.

Comment: `texput(foo, "<stuff>", prefix)` expects that `"<stuff>"` is going to be a string which `tex` will then put before the argument. When you supply a function, saying that it's prefix or postfix, etc., is not needed -- placement is handled by the function.

Comment: @RobertDodier - thank you, I think I understand it better, now. I thought the 3rd argument had to do with how Maxima defines the function (not sure why -- think I must've misunderstood the answer to an old question from the maxima-discuss list). Thanks for taking the time to clarify!